# Oozie realted Issue

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I modifed the job.properties file and i am using 2.6 version .
    Job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:54310
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/map-reduce

outputDir=map-reduce

ERROR::

Here m using resource manager as job Tracker  


ID                                                                            Status    Ext ID                 Ext Status Err Code
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000009-150428031755155-oozie-root-W@:start:                                  OK        -                      OK         -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000009-150428031755155-oozie-root-W@mr-node                                  RUNNING   job_1430213125476_0001 RUNNING    JA002
```

Comment: Hi @gaurav can you pls update the full logs of the error. in oozie it shows the running state ! can you please make the statement clear.

Comment: Where we can fine the full log ??..
I run this command and  it retrun me one jobID 
/opt/oozie-4.0.1/bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config /opt/oozie-4.0.1/examples/target/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties  -run
After that  i run
bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -info 0000009-150428031755155-oozie-root-W
which say the above error

Comment: First thing you have to verify the submitted job is succeeded or not. pls check on the <localhost> :8088(yarn webconsole) as the job is suceeded or killed or failed and find the User log located in the application master with the appropriate Jobid

Comment: I am not  able to access Browser .I can only access Command line Prompt

Comment: It is submitted but is failing while running, i think so

Comment: can you pls locate the metadata location in that go to namenode and userlogs or try the logs folder in hadoophome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76429/discussion-between-karthik-and-gaurav).

Answer (score 0):

JA002 is actually a permission denied exception.Just check whether the user has necessary access to HDFS.  To check the logs in command line we have an option like oozie job -log jobId.

Comment: Can u elaborate more on this

Comment: is it mandatory to create Oozie user ..can we run using root user

Comment: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: Unauthorized connection for super-user: roo
t from IP

Comment: In core-site.xml add the IP to the property hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts ,restart hadoop and try..